# How do I determine the number of dimensions of an array?

Tags: ruby

I have a method that uses transpose, but I do not want to apply this operation if the array has less than 2 dimensions. I am wondering how I can do this in ruby.

```
so for an array like [1,2] -> it should say 1D

and for an array like [[1,2],[1,2]] it should say 2D
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Comment: What should it do if the number of dimensions is inconsistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find it recursively:

```
def getDimension(array)
  if array.first.is_a?(Array)
    1 + getDimension(array.first)
  else
    1
  end
end
```

I know it is a bit crude and there probably someone who is able to make it much nicer, but the general idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Because Ruby arrays can hold anything this is fragile and a hack at best, but you could always just check to see if the *nth* element is an array, i.e.,

```
def is_2d(array)
  array.first.is_a?(Array)
end
```

I really don't like this, so if there is something better just slap me or downvote me into oblivion.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I might just try `#transpose` and `rescue IndexError, TypeError`, but another idea is:

```
x.map(&:class).uniq == [Array]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
a.map{|e| e.is_a?(Array)}.uniq == [true] ? "#{e.size}D" : "1D"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module MultiDArray #this could be a subclass of Array 
                   #if you can modify your callers
 def self.transposable?(array)
    array[0] && array[0][0] 
 end
 def self.dimensions(array)
    return 0 if array.nil?
    return self.dimensions(array[0]) if array[0].is_a?(Array)
    return 1
 end
 def self.dimension_to_s(array)
    "#{dimensions(array)}D"
 end
end


MultiDArray.transposable? #is probably what you're actually looking for.
```

This is presuming you're using normal ruby arrays and not `Matrix`es.
You've probably got worse data model problems to deal with if the arrays aren't regular, so one of these two methodologies is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fear errors, just anticipate them:

```
a.transpose rescue a
```